# Unable to .show scores in Music21

Tags: python, music21

I'm working in Jupyter Notebook. I've installed music21, musescore, set the xml path as below:

```
us = environment.UserSettings()
us['musicxmlPath'] ='Applications/musescore.app'
```

I've also run config, and see that musescore is being detected by music21. However, when I use the show method, I get the following error:

```
SubConverterFileIOException: png file of xml not found. Or file >999 pages?
```

Answer (score 1):

An .app file is a directory.  Inside the MuseScore.app directory is a bin directory and a file called mscore -- that's the actual name in the path.  It'd be much easier to run `python -m music21.configure` and let the automatic configuration program take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that file exists?
Try changing `Applications/musescore.app` to `/Applications/musescore.app`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer from [here](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/issues/348) wrote by GaetanBaert，It works well and now I can use show method.
He said that "you should change `os.system(musescoreRun)` line 891 of `subconverters.py` by `subprocess.run(musescoreRun)`. You need also to `import subprocess` at the start of `subconverters.py`."